# JS, minlength validationForm not working how it should

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to limit the user to enter 16 digits number for his card number input.
My problem is: if the user enters less than 16 numbers, an alert message will pop up.
What happens is: if he eneters 1 digit my condition works, if he enters more than 3 digits it will accept his input even though it's not 16!

here is my code:

```
<pre>
function validateForm() {
var b = document.forms["myForm"]["cnum"].value;
if (b == "" || isNaN(b) || b < 16){
alert("Input invalid, please enter your 16 digit Card Number");
return false;

<body>
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
 <label>Card Number</label>
  <input type="text" name="cnum" placeholder="4000 1234 5678 9010"  maxlength="16"/>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>
</form>  
 </body>

}
```

Comment: Oh, it worked, thanks.. didn't know that there's .length

Comment: you were checking the value of the string not the length.

Comment: Yes, i wanted to check the input value, but your previous answer helped me, thank you. @GauravSingh

Answer (score 0):

In your `if()`, you are checking for `b < 16`

If you want to check if the number **length** is not 16 numbers long, you should instead check for `b.length !== 16`

```
function validateForm() {
var b = document.forms["myForm"]["cnum"].value;
  if (b == "" || isNaN(b) || b.length !== 16){
    alert("Input invalid, please enter your 16 digit Card Number");
    return false;
  }
}
```